# 1000% optimized

Tags: word-choice

Previously, the execution time of a program was 30 seconds.

Now, with a more powerful computer, the execution time of the same program is 3 seconds.

Can we say "the execution time of the program with old computer vs. with new computer is **1000% optimized**"?

Comment: "Optimize" has a particular meaning in computer technology, and running the program on a faster machine does not optimize it. It just runs faster.

Comment: That wouldn't be optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the goal to communicate information effectively?
Then you'd use the phrase "10 times faster" or "10x faster".

1000% is harder to understand and rationalize than 10x.

If your goal is to show competitive advantage in a sales pitch with big numbers, then 1000% proves that point, but looks out of place.

Comment: Moreover, speaking of percentage increases does not work well with *optimized*, because the meaning of *optimized* makes it, effectively, a superlative (even though it is not grammatically a superlative).